# Artisan command is not outputting exception logging

Tags: php, laravel, exception, console, laravel-artisan

I am using a custom listener, which is extending the `Illuminate\Console\Command` class. Locally I am starting this listener with `php artisan mylistener:startlistening`

The problem here is, that whenever this listener stops because of some exception, nothing is shown in my console. Log messages do appear in the console. The logmessages are logged using the warn, error or info functions in the Command class.

EDIT: The same goes for any `artisan migrate:*` commands: Whenever something fails, no stack trace or error logging. Normal info/warning messages do show up in the console.

Laravel version is 5.4.27
PHP version is 7.1
OS Ubuntu 16.10

How can I make artisan show the exceptions in my console?

Comment: Try writing to the console directly, does that work? `$this->error('Something went wrong!');`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy  
Yes, all the logmessages make it to the console

Comment: Maybe also usefull: dd('something') ends up in the console aswell